# Not able to create word document in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

i am using WCF service to send mail with attachment.
in this WCF service i am creating one word document, pushing some data into this document. and attching this as attachment to mail. 
while creating word document am getting following error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Access is denied.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

can any one please help in this

Comment: Betrer Show the code concerning the life-cycle of the document. But running Word on any kind of Server is never a good idea.

Comment: have you looked into folder permissions for the user that is running the WCF service? Just in case it's a permission issue.

Comment: The context that the service is running under (Local System?) probably doesn't have access to launch word. I'm guessing if you run this same code in a windows app it works.  I guess it all depends on how it's hosted.

Comment: As a suggestion, if you're targeting at least Word2003 you should consider generating a XML doc, that can be generated easily on the fly and you don't require an Office installation on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) to be quite useful on msdn.  I think it's from 2009 but I think it's still accurate in your scenario. This basically explains that microsoft doesn't really support this sort of thing and alternatives you can do.

If you must use automation like this in your wcf service I would recommend launching the service under an account that has access to launch word.  I'm not too familiar with wcf but I assume this can be done.